# Remove the page number at the bottom center of each new chapter start page

Tags: numbering, fancyhdr, scrreprt, emptypage

I am making a thesis in LaTeX with `\documentclass{scrreprt}`. The `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` is loaded and customized. Default settings of page number I think is `\pagestyle{plain}` by report, which automatically adds page numbers in the bottom center  of every page. Right now I have two problems which I can not resolve:

1. I have removed the page numbers on chapter ackownlegement and abstract with `\pagestyle{empty}`; however, for the toc/ list of figure and table, `\pagestyle{empty}` and `\thispagestyle{empty}` do not work. I still have the plain style. Why are they not working? I want to remove the numbers on toc and list of Figure/Table
2. I tried to use the fancy pagestyle (in preamble and in separate .tex) to change the rest of documents/pages starting `1. chapter introduction`. Most of pages are correct but the starting page of every new chapter is still in `\pagestyle{plain}`. How could i change them into `\pagestyle{fancy}`?

This a minimum working example in my preamble:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage[left= 2.5cm,right = 2.5cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2 cm]{geometry}
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\hspace{4mm}}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
    \usepackage{sectsty}
    \setsansfont{Times New Roman}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{emptypage}
    \usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{Page \thepage}
    \lhead{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

    \begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}
    \include{01_title}
    \include{02_acknowlegements}
    \include{03_abstract}

    %\newpage
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents

    \newpage
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \listoffigures

    \newpage
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \listoftables

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \include{04_introduction}

    \end{document}
```

and in the introduction.tex i start with:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation and Purpose of the Thesis}
.......
```

in the following sreenshots you can see the fancy pagestyle i managed to achieve on the rest pages except the starting pages of new chapters:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do not use packages `sectsty`, `tocloft` and `fancyhdr` with a KOMA-Script class. Package `emptypage` is not needed with a KOMA-Script class. Package `fontspec` requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX. Do not use package `inputenc` with XeTeX or LuaTeX. With an uptodate TeX distribution it is not needed at all. Your Times New Roman selection is overwritten by package `lmodern`.

I would suggest to use KOMA-Script package **`scrlayer-scrpage`** for page header and footer:

```latex
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.\ }
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page \thepage}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}

\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{empty}{onselect=\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}{onselect=\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm, bottom = 2 cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\hspace{4mm}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.\ }
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page \thepage}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}

\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{empty}{onselect=\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}{onselect=\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\chapter{Title}\blindtext
\chapter{Acknowledgements}\blindtext
\chapter{Abstract}\blindtext

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really want to use package **`fancyhdr`** then redefine `\chapterpagestyle` when you change the page style:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm, bottom = 2 cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\hspace{4mm}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}
\chapter{Title}\blindtext
\chapter{Acknowledgements}\blindtext
\chapter{Abstract}\blindtext

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{fancy}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```